# Disable SonataUserBundle sonata.user.admin.group service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm working with SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle.

SonataUserBundle registers a service `sonata.user.admin.group` which is automatically detected by SonataAdminBundle to set links in the admin dashboard to group CRUD operations.

How can I disable `sonata.user.admin.group`? I've been following that recipes in Symfony2 documentation:

- [How to Override any Part of a Bundle - Services and Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration)
- [Compiling the Container - Creating a Compiler Pass](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass)
- [Working with Container Parameters and Definitions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html)

So far, I have the following code in my bundle definition to add a compiler pass:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
  parent::build($container);

  $container->addCompilerPass(new CompilerPass());
}
```

And here it is the compiler pass:

```
<?php

namespace NS\Service\CompilerPass;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
       $container->removeDefinition('sonata.user.admin.group');
    }
}
```

I thought that this should work but no. Symfony is throwing an exception telling me that `sonata.user.admin.group` service does not exist. But it exists, and if I do `$container->getDefinition('sonata.user.admin.group')` the actual definition is return.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try marking the service as abstract and set its `public` property to false e.g.

```
#in any services.yml
services:
    sonata.user.admin.group:
      abstract: true
      public: false
    #...
```

**Addition to completeness:**

And add to the CompilerPass:

```
$container->getDefinition('sonata.user.admin.group')->setSynthetic(true);
```

Comment: That works! But adding the following to the `CompilerPass`:

$container->getDefinition('sonata.user.admin.group')->setSynthetic(true);

Comment: Implementing both suggested parts of the solution throws the error "A synthetic service ("sonata.user.admin.group") must be public." on `cache:clear`. But just the first bit works fine for me on its own: what difference does adding the `CompilerPass` part make?

Answer (score 1):

You've removed the service definition but it's still used on the dashboard. That's why Symfony complains (dashboard tries to access it). It's not an optional service.

You could try to overwrite the dashboard template and avoid using the service? This way service wouldn't be called and you wouldn't have to remove it. If service is not used it's never created.

Alternative would be overloading the service with your implementation.

Comment: Ok, of course, that makes sense. But I think that dashboard template has nothing to do with it: http://goo.gl/vc4rk and I neither see any relation in SonataUserBundle views: http://goo.gl/oSjdY Any idea where it is managed?

Comment: Thans a lot @JakubZalas, your answer pointed straight to the right problem